# does the domain can be considered as subset of it image under 1 to 1 function?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Let $f\colon X \to X$ be a one-to-one function and let $A \subseteq X$. Does $A \subseteq f(A)$?

I ask because I found a step which not clear to me in this paper 
http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/stong2.pdf
page(328) proposition 8 .which is $f'(\tau)\supseteq \tau$.

Comment: $A$ is always a subset of $A$. I'm not sure what you're really asking.

Comment: Is $A \subset X$ ?

Comment: yes sorry I edit it means A subset of X

Answer (score 4):

No.

As long as $f$ isn't the identity, you can choose some $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=y\neq x$. Then consider the singleton set $A=\{x\}$.

Comment: ok I agree with you the function in the give case will not satisfy A subset of f(A) . But my point is when we can consider A subset f(A) as mentioned in the paper" f`(τ)⊇ τ in the paper the reason given is by fineness?

Comment: The statement $f'(T)\supset T$ is saying that every open set $A\subset X$ is the image of some other open set in $X$ (remember, $T$ is the topology on $X$). Namely, that open set is $f^{-1}(A)$, which is open by continuity of $f$, (and certainly $f(f^{-1}(A))=A$, since $f$ is onto).

Comment: ok let me write in details let A belong to T then f^-1(A) is open (since f is continuous i.e belong to T) and also we will have f(f^-1(A))=A (since f is one to one) and hence the image of an open set is open again open (i.e belong to T) then A belong to the Image of f(T) (i.e if A belong to T then A belong to f(T))

Comment: ok we can apply the same steps above on infinite sets ???I know injective and surjective are not equivalent between infinite sets   but the steps you wrote can be used in the same why ok ?? what finiteness give us here

Comment: What I wrote is always true, but that alone does not establish a 1-1 correspondence $T\rightarrow T$. All it does is establish a surjection from $T$ to $T$. But $T$ is finite, so in fact it establishes a bijection.

Comment: Ok thanx in fact "I  did the same steps few days a go but wasn't reasonable enough to me .....although I know "surjective and injective are equivalent by finitness>>>>>>" Thank you"

Answer (score 2):

It is not generally true that $A\subseteq f(A)$ for $A$ a subset of the domain of injective (or even bijective) map $X\to X$. Take the map on $\mathbb{Z}$ that takes every number to its negative; then it is not true for $A=\{1,2,3\}$, for instance. It may of course be the case under certain circumstances (as it definitely is if $f=id_X$).

Answer (score 2):

As already answered, no. But $f(A)$ is "like" $A$ in the sense that there is a bijective correspondence between both ($f$!).